# Is there a way to pass 'missing' object to .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `.append()` function can take multiple arguments, either flat or in an array.  I have some code where I need to append 3 items, one of which might not exist, like:

```
whatever.append(always).append(maybe).append(alwaysToo);
/* or */
whatever.append(always, maybe, alwaysToo);
/* or */
var arrayOfThoseThree = [ always, maybe, alwaysToo ];
whatever.append(arrayOfThoseThree);
```

I can not make out from the jQuery docs what, if anything, the value of `maybe` should be to say "*just ignore this one*":

```
maybe = '';
maybe = null;
maybe = undefined;
maybe = ???
```

as in:

```
maybe = needMaybe ? $('<blah...>') : ignoreThisValue;
```

I could, of course, do something like:

```
whatever.append(always);
if (maybe) whatever.append(maybe);
whatever.append(alwaysToo);
```

but that's **ugly** (especially as this is part of a larger chain).

And I could experiment with different values until I find one that "*works*", but I was hoping there was an "official" documented way that won't fail to work some future day because I was using an "undocumented feature".

Point me in the right direction?

**[EDIT]**

I was wondering in general, but the concrete example in front of me is:

```
var titl = this.dataset.title;               /* optional */
var ifr = $('<iframe>');
var bas = $('<base href="' + document.baseURI + '">');
var ttl = titl ? $('<title>' + titl + '</title>') : null;   /* HERE */
var lnk = $('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css">');
/* ... */
ifr.contents().find('head').append(bas, ttl, lnk);
```

Comment: What happens if you test it?

Comment: Could we see more of your logic. Why would the variables hold a null/empty value?

Comment: testing may find a way that "works", but it won't tell me if there is a supported way that won't break mysteriously in the future.

Comment: @JohnHascall, what would happen, if `maybe` was an empty Array for example. what would be the result of the append? And I've not chewcked, but how does `append()` handle `null` and `undefined` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
whatever.append([always, maybe, alwaysToo].filter(item => !!item));
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happens in the jQuery code (the version I'm using anyway).
**Note that this defines what "*works*" today, not what is documented to work and continue working in the future.**

The `.append()` function is written similarly to many others in that `domManip()` does much of the work:

```
append: function() {
        return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
                if ( this.nodeType === 1 ||
                     this.nodeType === 11 ||
                     this.nodeType === 9 ) {
                        var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
                        target.appendChild( elem );
                }
        });
},
```

and the first thing `domManip()` does is:

```
domManip: function( args, callback ) {
        // Flatten any nested arrays
        args = concat.apply( [], args );
```

then it calls `buildFragment()`:

```
        fragment = jQuery.buildFragment( args, ... );
```

which does:

```
buildFragment: function( elems, context, scripts, selection ) {
        var /* ..., */ i = 0;
        for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
                elem = elems[ i ];
                if ( elem || elem === 0 ) {
                      /* ... process this argument ... */
                }
        }
```

So empty arrays get squashed by `Array.prototype.concat()` and then anything that fails the test `( elem || elem === 0 )` gets ignored.

So, in fact, when `ttl` could be `null`, all of these (***currently***) do "*the right thing*":

```
whatever.append( bas,  ttl,   lnk);
whatever.append([bas,  ttl,   lnk]);
whatever.append([bas],[ttl], [lnk]);
whatever.append( bas, [ttl],  lnk);

whatever.append(bas).append( ttl ).append(lnk);
whatever.append(bas).append([ttl]).append(lnk);
```

But, as near as I can find, the documentation makes no statements about a value or values which you can use which will safely be ignored (now and forever).

Thus the safest course of action (at least where `=>` is supported) is the Answer from Assan:

```
whatever.append( [bas, ttl, lnk].filter( e => !!e ) );
```